# Delete a record from when current timestamp is greater than a fixed timestamp value in existing column

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

I have a table `Coupons` with a column `endDate` datatype as timestamp without timezone. If I set value of that column as **06/16/2018 12:45:00+5:30**. Is there any way that the record containing this timestamp automatically deletes when the **current timestamp** is greater than the **endDate**

Something like `delete from Coupons where endDate < NOW()` query that could be executed automatically.

Can this be done using POSTGRESQL using some trigger function?
Through nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

You would want a trigger that fires based off of time changes, which don't happen. You'd want something like [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) that fire time-based commands. So you could write a function such as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION expire_coupons() RETURNS void AS $$
   DELETE FROM coupons WHERE enddate < now();
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

and then have your pg_cron job or even an external script in a crontab call `SELECT expire_coupons();`. Or just run the delete itself since it isn't very complex.

Comment: This would mean scheduling the cronjob to call the function at a specified time. Is it possible to schedule the cronjob according to the endDate ?

Comment: Really you'd call the function regularly (once a day, once per hour, etc). Whenever it runs it'll look at any rows where enddate has elapsed and delete them.